# How to set specifict users to be reviewers

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and git. I have a branch policy where pull requests have to be approved by at least one user (reviewer) before merge.

But I don't want every user to be a reviewer, I would like to set up a group of users or specific ones that can be reviewers. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an option to require specific reviewers for portions of your code. You should specify the paths and add reviewers to each path. In its simplest form, you can require minimum 1 reviewer, and add him/her to the repo root path. It might look something like this:

[image: Code review gate]
This looks like a powerful mechanism. For example, you can specify that `/source` part of the code is reviewed by the team lead, `/buildscript` part is reviewed by a build guy, and `/tests` are examined by QA people! :-)

Comment: But adding reviewers to that list will imply that all reviewers from the list must approve the Pull Request before merging the code, right? In my case, it would be enough the approval of only one of them.

Comment: I don't think so, although it is better verify on practice. I think that the "Required" checkbox in front of each Path field dictates whether this particular reviewer feedback is required. The system will block the pull request from merging in case the minimum number of reviewers (`1` in the sample above) is not met.

Comment: @leosbrf You can add a group instead of individuals.  If any member of that group approves, it counts for the whole group.